# MySQL SELECT, OUTPUT THEN DELETE

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, select

I'm using this query within a WP installation to output the lowest a code from a custom table. It successfully outputs the row with the lowest ID, and with a taken of '0'. So, that all works great - however, within the same function I want the outputted code to then have its taken SET to 1, instead of 0. I have tried so many variations but can't quite crack it. Any ideas? Thanks.

```
function voucher_func() {
    global $wpdb;
    $vouchers = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT MIN(code) AS code FROM vouchers WHERE taken=0");
    foreach($vouchers as $voucher){
        return $voucher->code;
    }
}
add_shortcode( 'latest_voucher', 'voucher_func' );
```

Following on from the first bits of advice, i have got this far. This still outputs the right data, but doesnt update the 'taken' to 1

```
function voucher_func() {
global $wpdb;
$vouchers = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT MIN(code) AS code FROM vouchers WHERE taken=0");
foreach($vouchers as $voucher){
return $voucher->code;
}
}
$wpdb->update('vouchers', array('taken' => 1), array('code' => $voucher->code));

add_shortcode( 'latest_voucher', 'voucher_func' );
```

Here's what i have now ...

```
function voucher_func() {
global $wpdb;
$vouchers = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT MIN(code) AS code FROM vouchers WHERE taken=0");
foreach($vouchers as $voucher){
$wpdb->update('vouchers', array('taken' => 1), array('code' => $voucher->code));
return $voucher->code;
}
}

add_shortcode( 'latest_voucher', 'voucher_func' );
```

Here's my final and working code:

```
function voucher_func() {
global $wpdb;
$vouchers = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT MIN(code) AS code FROM vouchers WHERE taken=0");
foreach($vouchers as $voucher){
return $voucher->code;
}
}

add_shortcode( 'latest_voucher', 'voucher_func' );

function action_wpcf7_mail_sent( $contact_form ) {
global $wpdb;
$vouchers1 = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT MIN(code) AS code FROM vouchers WHERE taken=0");
foreach($vouchers1 as $voucher1){
$wpdb->update('vouchers', array('taken' => 1), array('code' => $voucher1->code));
}
};

add_action( 'wpcf7_mail_sent', 'action_wpcf7_mail_sent', 10, 1 );
```

Comment: What *have* you tried that didn't work?

Comment: DELETE FROM voucher ( .... SELECT ... ) and other variations :-(

Comment: That was as a last resort. I would rather keep the record and use SET taken=1 if possible, but i couldn't get that to work either.

Comment: so then `UPDATE vouchers  ....`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to use [wpdb->update()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#UPDATE_rows):

```
$wpdb->update('vouchers', array('taken' => 1), array('code' => $RetrievedVoucherCode));
```

Comment: I appreciate the advice, see my updated code above though. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: @dmt You need to put your call to $wpdb->update somewhere where it has access to the voucher code. Inside the foreach loop before the return would be a perfect place.

Comment: Hi jbafford, moving that new line before the return does update the taken values from 0 to 1, but it does all of them, instead of just the lowest one (which was being captured before in my return). Any clues?

Comment: Are the codes unique? Because that really should only be updating the codes where `code == $voucher->code`.

Comment: The codes are each unique. I just checked and if i manually set (updating the db directly) just the first one set to 1 and the rest on 0, then submit my form, it changes the following three codes from 0 to 1, so it updates three instead of just that single code. Bizarre.

Comment: @dmt Can you update your question with your updated code?

Comment: Hi, i've just noticed that the vouchers are knocked out each time the page reloads. So it does work, but my function kicks in each time there's a page refresh. So thanks for your help!!!

Answer (score 0):

If codes are unique
`UPDATE vouchers SET taken=1 WHERE code = (SELECT MIN(code) FROM vouchers WHERE taken=0)`

Answer (score 0):

You can try combining the UPDATE and SELECT statements, similarly to what is [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24850579/mysql-combine-update-and-select-query).